# MySql, Ninject and NHibernate - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, ninject

I'm using a MySQL database which I am accessing with Fluent NHibernate and have wired up Session-Per-Request with Ninject like so:

```
        Kernel.Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(context => Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
            .InRequestScope();
```

I did have `OnDeactivation(x=>x.Dispose());` but have been told it is not necessary as Ninject will call Dispose for you.

Everything works great except for a few times when I double click on a link that causes a read I get "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

I have read that I need to enable Multiple Active Record Sets (MARS) however I beleive this is not supported by MySQL.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this error?

Comment: how is your ISessionFactory wired up?  are you using a Transaction?

Comment: No, I'm using the a generic Repository with a transaction inside each method on that. How would I use a transaction across the whole request?

Comment: Where's the binding for `ISessionFactory`?

Comment: Also, have you verified that this error does *not* occur when you open and close sessions explicitly? It's very possible that this actually has nothing to do with Ninject and that some part of the code is not properly taking into account NHibernate's lazy evaluation. I'd start by looking for any threads, async tasks, async pages, or objects that might outlive the session (e.g. being stored in the Session or Cache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to using NHibernate in multiple threads via a Parrell.ForEach.

So don't use a single session in multiple threads, basically!